# Azure Container Instance being recreated

Tags: azure, dock, azure-container-instances, clamav

I have created a clamav container instance (mkodockx/docker-clamav:alpine) within Azure but every few days it tends to be recreated by itself pulling the image over and over again, as you can see in the screengrab.

[image]

Is something wrong? Why would it be doing this?

I also have an Azure App Service which makes calls to the container instance over port 3310 but every few days it can't reach it... [image]

What is going on? Why can't it be reached? I reached out to Azure support but they were super unhelpful

I'm no expert in containerization so please dumb it down for me :)

Thanks

Comment: Do you check if there is any task restart the container? Or anything wrong and cause the container restart.

Comment: Cheers @CharlesXu where would I check for a task that restarts the container... also how can I check if there is anything wrong that is causing the container to restart? It's all very black box to me

Answer (score 0):

I would start with setting the Restart Policy of the Azure Container Groups

There are three policies for the Azure Container Groups :

1. Never
2. Always
3. On Failure

The default policy is **Always**

You could change the Policy and observe the output in your case :

You could use the below [commandlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-restart-policy#:%7E:text=Container%20restart%20policy,-When%20you%20create&text=Containers%20in%20the%20container%20group%20are%20never%20restarted,containers%20run%20at%20most%20once.&text=Containers%20in%20the%20container%20group%20are%20restarted%20only%20when%20the,are%20run%20at%20least%20once.) to change the Restart Policy :

```
az container create \
    --resource-group <myResourceGroup> \
    --name <mycontainer> \
    --image <IMAGE> \
    --restart-policy OnFailure #(or Never)
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#issues-during-container-group-runtime)

Comment: @Andrew - Just wanted to check with you whether the above helped ? if it had helped, please consider marking the answer as solution. :)

Comment: OnFailure is the default one policy